# Navigation drawer item onClick opens another menu

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

There is a navigation drawer in my app and my requirement is to open another menu in the same navigation drawer with a fancy right to left animation when a navigation drawer item is clicked. There must also be a back button that will lead the newly loaded menu to the previous main menu.

For example :

[image: Something similar to the gif given below :]

Comment: Add two navigation Drawers and hide one and display that drawer on item click.?

Comment: It should be easy. keep the parent as frame layout and do a transition of views inside it.

Comment: It would be helpful if you provide some code that will implement it.

Answer (score 0):

I did it by applying the following techniques, hopefully it will be helpful for 
 you.

1. First of all you need single drawer keeping in FrameLayout.
2. For onClick on drawer item to open another menu you need ListFragment
3. Then do it with Fragment Transaction on FrameLayout when a item is clicked.